# How to Change email hosting provider only

Tags: email, dns, web, hosting

This is my scenario:
**Current scenario**: My website is hosted with company A and domain and emails is with company B.

**What I want**:  I want to change my email hosting provider only.My website should hosted with company A ,domain with company B and email with company C.

Please suggest with what parameter is need to change.

Thanks.

Comment: Transfer your domain to B, and set up MX records to point to C.

Comment: my domain is already on B,I just want to seprate my email from B and host it on to C.

Comment: So set up a MX record to C, per their instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not mentioned that whose DNS services you have been using. I believe you are using DNS services of domain registrar (Company B).  Now, you just need to login to Domain control panel provided by domain registrar and add following MX records to point mail services to company C.

mail .... A .... IP address of Mail server (Company C)

MX ....mail.domain.com (0)

If you are using DNS services of Web Hosting provider, you need to add above records at DNS control provided by Host.

Comment: I am using DNS services  of B and my mail server is also  B. I want to change my  email services to  C from B.so please guide me what to add on DNS control panel of B.
NOTE: My web hosting is A.

Comment: If you are using DNS services of B, you just need to login to Domain control panel/DNS control panel and change MX records as shown in previous reply. You can also contact your registrar to set MX records you.